QWebEngineView not rendering pydeck html
I am currently trying to open an html file generated with pydeck in a Pyqt5 webview window. I can open it on my browser (firefox, if that's relevant) and it works correctly. However, if I try to open it in pyqt5, a blank window will open and I get the following errors:
js: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '='
js: Uncaught ReferenceError: createDeck is not defined

I do not get these errors in my browser.
I have also tried saving the resulting HTML to a string instead of a file and sending it directly to window.setHtml. The result is the same. I have used this same code to show other HTML files and it has worked correctly.
Here is the code I am using:
r.to_html("test2.html")
data = Path("test2.html").read_text(encoding="utf8")
app = QApplication(sys.argv + ["--no-sandbox"])
window = QWebEngineView()
window.setHtml(data)
window.resize(640,480)
window.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())

Here is the generated HTML as well:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>pydeck</title>
        <script src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.13.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@deck.gl/jupyter-widget@~9.0.*/dist/index.js'></script>
    <style>
    body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#deck-container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

#deck-container canvas {
  z-index: 1;
  background: none;
}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="deck-container">
    </div>
  </body>
  <script>
    const container = document.getElementById('deck-container');
    const jsonInput = {
  "initialViewState": {
    "bearing": 0,
    "latitude": 41.150537,
    "longitude": -8.586245,
    "pitch": 45,
    "zoom": 11
  },
  "layers": [
    {
      "@@type": "TripsLayer",
      "currentTime": 21420,
      "data": [
        {
          "coordinates": [
            [
              -8.582416,
              41.160716
            ],
            [
              -8.586245,
              41.150537
            ],
            [
              -8.592978,
              41.146697
            ],
            [
              -8.598349,
              41.148796
            ],
            [
              -8.605901,
              41.149785
            ],
            [
              -8.609299,
              41.152277
            ],
            [
              -8.616723,
              41.157107
            ],
            [
              -8.622246,
              41.158585
            ],
            [
              -8.628282,
              41.160575
            ],
            [
              -8.636347,
              41.165549
            ],
            [
              -8.641766,
              41.172962
            ],
            [
              -8.646498,
              41.177255
            ],
            [
              -8.652149,
              41.182422
            ],
            [
              -8.654466,
              41.188101
            ],
            [
              -8.655771,
              41.194161
            ],
            [
              -8.655559,
              41.200294
            ],
            [
              -8.654541,
              41.216067
            ],
            [
              -8.656593,
              41.233013
            ],
            [
              -8.658212,
              41.238246
            ],
            [
              -8.661807,
              41.246233
            ],
            [
              -8.668018,
              41.254953
            ],
            [
              -8.679515,
              41.270297
            ],
            [
              -8.693703,
              41.285251
            ],
            [
              -8.699238,
              41.293684
            ],
            [
              -8.704004,
              41.300492
            ],
            [
              -8.714209,
              41.315077
            ],
            [
              -8.718681,
              41.321222
            ],
            [
              -8.720721,
              41.334225
            ],
            [
              -8.725555,
              41.340402
            ],
            [
              -8.728122,
              41.345965
            ],
            [
              -8.735826,
              41.353983
            ],
            [
              -8.73987,
              41.359096
            ],
            [
              -8.745225,
              41.364643
            ],
            [
              -8.749558,
              41.368953
            ],
            [
              -8.754122,
              41.373456
            ],
            [
              -8.758081,
              41.378126
            ]
          ],
          "timestamps": [
            21240,
            21420,
            21540,
            21600,
            21660,
            21780,
            21900,
            21960,
            22080,
            22200,
            22320,
            22380,
            22440,
            22560,
            22680,
            22800,
            22920,
            23100,
            23220,
            23340,
            23520,
            23820,
            24060,
            24240,
            24420,
            24660,
            24780,
            24960,
            25140,
            25260,
            25440,
            25560,
            25680,
            25800,
            25860,
            26040
          ]
        }
      ],
      "getColor": [
        253,
        128,
        93
      ],
      "getPath": "@@=coordinates",
      "getTimestamps": "@@=timestamps",
      "id": "71700afb-ebee-4f1c-863e-dc131bc2c8e6",
      "opacity": 0.8,
      "rounded": true,
      "trailLength": 600,
      "widthMinPixels": 5
    }
  ],
  "mapProvider": "carto",
  "mapStyle": "https://basemaps.cartocdn.com/gl/dark-matter-gl-style/style.json",
  "views": [
    {
      "@@type": "MapView",
      "controller": true
    }
  ]
};
    const tooltip = true;
    const customLibraries = null;
    const configuration = null;

    const deckInstance = createDeck({
                  container,
      jsonInput,
      tooltip,
      customLibraries,
      configuration
    });

  </script>
</html>


The setHtml() docs do say that the "HTML document is loaded immediately, whereas external objects are loaded asynchronously". Since you're using an external script, when the HTML is loaded the script declaring createDeck() isn't yet. Try removing that function call, and connect the page's loadingFinished() to a function that calls runJavaScript().

If the embedded script is executed after a short delay, it will work correctly: window.setTimeout(function() { const container = ... }, 500);. However, if you have no control over the embedded script that pydeck outputs, you could try generating the html with r.to_html("test2.html", offline=True). This might make it possible to load the html from a local file using setUrl(QUrl.fromLocalFile(path_to_file)).
